# Is there a container-neutral way of enabling directory listing?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jetty

I have a web app which contains some static contents. I'd like to make it browse-able. I test the web app in my local environment using Jetty and deploy it in production environment which uses Tomcat. Note that in Tomcat there are many other webapps been deployed and I do not want to interfere their settings.

It seems that I can do it by changing the settings of default servlet, for Tomcat:

```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>listing</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>debug</param-name>
           <param-value>0</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>listings</param-name>
           <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
```

But it will cause problem when run it in Jetty environment since there is no `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` exists.

So here comes the question: Is there a way that I can enable directory listing for both Jetty and Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, don't use the default servlet of the container, create your own that does what you want and register it accordingly.

[edit] default servlets are a convenience, nothing more

Comment: As you are one of the developers of Jetty, would you be able to illustrate how this could be done programmatically, independent of the container? Do you know of any examples one could check?

Comment: My point was that both Jetty and Tomcat have these DefaultServlets for convenience only, you could achieve the same behavior by writing your own servlet to serve static content, or even grab Jetty's default servlet, pull it into your package space, resolve any dependencies and adapt as needed. The servlet class in the original question would just be updated with your new servlet.